# Writing data into a single file for Azure instead of part files

Tags: azure-blob-storage, mosaic-decisions

I am trying to write a file to my **Azure Storage** using **Mosaic Decisions**. I want to write the file to *Azure* as a **single file** and not **part files**. How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to simply switch on the toggle in your Writer Node Configuration menu(Double click on the writer node) for Single File Output.

The file would be written into a single file if this toggle is enabled.

[image: Refer the screenshot for the toggle]